# Swapping decks between versions of DOPW

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

I have both 2013 & 2014 DOPW on my laptop, how can I swap decks between the two???

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  The cards supported by each game are completely separate, so the decks are not interchangeable.